# CORS NODEJS Y REACTJS Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express, cors

estoy teniendo problema con los cors, cuando hago la prueba en POSTMAN me funciona, yo se que los cors te permiten que te hagan peticion de otras URL, Lo tengo subido a Heroku y me funciona pero al hacer la peticion desde del frontend me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cor en NodeJS:

```
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const app = express()

app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

app.set('PORT' , process.env.PORT || 4000)

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
 res.send('Conexion correctamente:')
})

app.use('/pago'  ,require('./mercadopago/mp'))

module.exports = app
```

desde el FrontEnd haciend la peticion:

```
        await axios.post('https://tilaindumentaria-backend.herokuapp.com/pago' , formClient)
    .then(resp=>{
        setDataLink(resp.data.meesage.init_point)
        console.log(resp.data.meesage.init_point)
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err.data)
    })
```

mi pregunta es como resuelvo este problema? por que vi en mucho post que el problema es del backend pero ya ya habilite los CORS en el backend

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que subiste los cambios en tu back en heroku? El middleware de cors luce correcto. No debería dar ese problema.

Comment: Si lo subí, además si algo está mal me saltaría un error al abrir el link de heroku, por eso me parece raro este problema